# Swift - CollectionViewCell label is moving position after I reload it

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that contains some `UICollectionViewCell`'s.  Each of these cells has two labels, the one in the upper left is the date of that cell, and the other is a monetary amount. I have the position of both labels set by constraints in story board.

The monetary label comes from CoreData and is displayed when first opening the app.

I have a button that can be clicked to add a new amount to whichever cell is selected.  The button saves the new amount to CoreData, and then calls `self.collection.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(self.collection.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!)`.

When the cell reloads the monetary label is positioned differently than the other cells.

The debugger allowed me to see that `reloadItemsAtIndexPath` is taking me to the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function and executing `cell.dateAmount.text = "$\(Int(amount))"`.

Everything is working as I intended, except that the label's position is getting moved up a few pixels.  Any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Comment: I think this problem is related to auto layout of collectionviewcell labels, please check the autolayout

Comment: Can you clarify on check the auto layout, I'm not sure what you mean.  I have a width, height, and bottom constraint set, then have it centered horizontally in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why reloading the cell was causing the constraints to break, but I found a solution by putting the two labels in a stackview.  Now when I update the label it stays in its original position and only the text changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you made width and height constraints.When the font size changed,the content move up(or down).The solution is just remove them.Or fix font size like this:
[image]

Comment: I already have the Autoshrink set to Fixed Font Size.  I tried removing the width and height constraints and I'm still getting the same results.  My font size isn't changing, I'm just updating the label with new text.  The thing I can't really understand is that the code I'm calling to update the label is the same code that is called to set the label initially, but it's breaking the constraint the second time around.

Comment: @Setleaf Maybe your constraints conflict.

Comment: I definitely think it's something to do with the constraints, I just can't seem to figure out what it is, or why it's happening.  In storyboard, Xcode isn't giving me any issues and all of my constraints have blue lines around them.  The constraints are working when you're initially brought to the view that contains the collectionView, they just aren't displaying correctly after I update the label a second or third time.

Comment: @Setleaf storyboard check constraints only depending on current size.I think remake these constraints maybe help.It sometimes works.

Comment: This app is only for iPhone, so all of my constraints are set in the regular height, compact width size class.